# How to search an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Say I have an array of strings

```
arr = ['sandra', 'sam', 'sabrina', 'scott', 'mark', 'melvin']
```

How would I search this array just like I would an active record object in Rails. For example, the query "sa" would return `['sandra', 'sam', 'sabrina']`.

Thanks!

Comment: in case you wonder about such things in the future, check out the ruby api: http://ruby-doc.org/core/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
arr.grep(/^sa/)
```

Comment: Uh... if that's an in-memory array, then the above doesn't make _any_ sql hits.

Comment: For e.g. If I have to search the whole name `sabrina `, then rather looping each name, regex or grep will give some performance?

Answer (score 31):

```
>> arr.select {|s| s.include? 'sa'}
=> ["sandra", "sam", "sabrina"]
```

Answer (score 14):

A combination of `select` method and regex would work

```
arr.select {|a| a.match(/^sa/)}
```

This one looks for prefixes, but it can be changed to substrings or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.select{|x|x[/^sa/]}
```